# Indexing of pointer when accessing elements of an array

Tags: c, arrays, pointers

I'm a beginner and I'm trying to understand how multidimensional arrays work.

So far, I've come this code snippet that i do not understand:

```
int arr[] = { 3, 5, 6, 7, 9 };
int (*ptr)[5] = &arr;
```

Ok so. 
I understand that ptr is a pointer pointing to an array of 5 elements.

But what is the '&' doing?? Is ptr pointing to the beginning address of 'arr'? But isnt 'arr' already an address? Why is there an '&' then?
Also. What is the significance of the indexing 5? Because when i try to give any other number besides 5, it throws an error.

I'm sorry if all this sounds silly but I'm so confused! Help!

Comment: I didn't get you?

Comment: You do not _index_ with the 5 here, but you declare a pointer to an array with 5 elements.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here, you have a variable `arr` with type `array of 5 int`:

```
int arr[] = { 3, 5, 6, 7, 9 };
```

Here, you declare a pointer `ptr` to `array of 5 int`:

```
int (*ptr)[5]
```

This gets the address of `arr` with type `pointer to array of 5 int`

```
&arr
```

and this assignment works, since the pointer types are equal:

```
int (*ptr)[5] = &arr;
```

Now if you change the type of `ptr` to another type, i.e. `pointer to array of 6 int`:

```
int (*ptr)[6];
```

then the assignment no longer works, since the pointer types mismatch now. This is why you get an error.

Note: the `[5]` in this code does *not* index anything, but is just a part of the variable declaration (number of elements in the array)

Comment: Ok so for `int a[3];`, the address of a is a pointer to array of 3 elements? 
(Or does that hold good only when you assign values to the elements at the time of initialisation itself? )

Comment: @bobthebuilder Yes, `&a` is of type int (*)[3] then.

Comment: Ok makes sense. Thank You!

Answer (score 0):

Your array only has one dimension, so it's not multidimensional.

Your array has 5 elements, and since arrays are zero-based, accessing element [5] (the sixth element) actually results in undefined behavior.

`arr` is not an address, it's an array. `&` is the address-of operator.

Comment: Here's the thing. The second line of the code. Isn't it kinda equivalent to `*p=a;`?